# Internet Explorer and Caching

Tags: internet-explorer, browser-cache

Imagine this:  two identical computers running the same OS (Windows XP) and the same version of IE (v8.0) on the same network behind the same proxy server.

The users of each computer access our web application (hosted outside the network).  One user ("Alan") did so in the middle of a deploy and cached a bunch of crap.  The other user ("Bob") waited until after the deploy (then some fixed patches) and is running smoothly.

So after the deploy was properly complete, Alan tries to access the application again.  Gets all kinds of problems.  The typical response from tech support, "Clear the cache and try again."  Did that - no fix.  It's strange because most of the site appears, only select images and some rather simple HTML.

Question:  How do we completely obliterate Alan's cache so he can enjoy the app as Bob in the next cubicle is?

We tried Ctrl+F5
We tried Tools->Internet Options->(Browsing History) Delete.
We tried it again then rebooted.
We tried Tools->Internet Options->(Browsing History) Settings/View Files and manually deleting everything we see there.

After every attempt Bob keeps sadistically snickering at Alan's misfortune.

If it's important, the web application is a PHP/Javascript app hosted on a LAMP stack.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the "Every time I visit the webpage" option in the Tools->Internet Options->(Browsing History) Settings and see if that helps.